# I didn't understand java boolean

Tags: boolean

I'm new at java and I didn't understand boolean very well. Can someone explain boolean?

> What is it?
>
> Where will I use it?
>
> Why ı use?

Comment: Please don't be afraid to use boolean. Boolean very good for you. You use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boolean value is one with two choices: true or false, like yes or no, 1 or 0.

```
boolean isSunday= true;
```

So instead of typing int or double or string, you just type boolean (with a lower case "b"). After the name of you variable, you can assign a value of either true or false. 
This is how to use. By the way, boolean's value is false default in Java.

```
boolean isSunday= true;
if ( isSunday ) {
System.out.println("it's Sunday!");
}
else {
System.out.println("it's not Sunday");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is it?

`boolean` is a data type to represent `true/false` value.

> Where will I use it?

In your java programs for instance a flag to know if an item is found in list or not.

> Why ı use?

To save memory and enhance readability.